# Docker Compose Dependencies

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Is it possible to postpone the startup of a container based the availability of a separate HTTP service. For example, only start the container if port 8080 is running?

Comment: Docker 1.12 introduces [HEALTHCHECK](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/healthcheck), but the missing piece is `docker-compose` need to be aware of it and start next service when the healthcheck passed. There is an open issue that you might want to check: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/374

Answer (score 1):

That sort of application-level service check isn't available in `docker-compose`.  You would need to implement the necessary logic in your docker images.

For example, if you have something that depends on a web service, you could have your `CMD` run a script that does something like:

```
while ! curl -sf http://servicehost:8080/; do
    sleep 1
done

exec myprogram
```

Another option is to set a restart policy of `always` on your containers, and have them fail if the target service isn't available.  Docker will continue to restart your container until it keeps running.